# Миграция с GMGridView на UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview

Решил заменить старую библиотеку  [CMGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView)  на родные платформе компоненты (в частности, `UICollectionView`). У `CMGridView` было замечательное свойство `layoutStrategy`, которое могло иметь значение в виде объекта класса `GMGridViewLayoutHorizontalPagedStrategy`. При это получалось постранично просматриваемый контейнер. Мне необходимо получить подобное поведение для `UICollectionView`. Я пробовал установить у свойства `pagingEnabled` значение `true`, но поведение получается совсем не то - на каждой странице присутствуют кусочки ячеек, невместившихся на страницу. Есть ли какое-нибудь простое решение этой проблемы? Не хочется тратить время на реализацию такого вручную.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать отступи (padding) в настройках справа "pagingEnabled = false".

Comment: @OrestMykha Не могу найти свойство padding, именно его надо редактировать?

Comment: Когда виделяете CollectionView справа в storyboard на четвертой вкладке scrollView

Comment: @OrestMykha Я попробовал сделать то что Вы посоветовали, но мне это к сожалению не помогло. Я сейчас пробую сделать следующее - каждую страницу представить в виде отдельной секции и для неё рассчитывать промежутки между строками и столбцами в UICollectionView (а также размеры краёв). Сдаётся мне что данная идея далеко не самая лучшая, но ничего другого на ум не приходит, да и время поджимает.